Combining two ASP.NET MVC projects
I have 2 separate ASP.NET MVC applications (Project1.sln, Project2.sln) using Entity Framework in VS 2019. Both applications work fine if the project/solution is loaded separately.
When I add Project2 in Project1, I get a long list of errors.
What's the best way to combine these two projects into one solution?

You need to add both projects to the solution - not to one another.... or what exactly do you mean by "combine two projects" ?? Please explain

"When I add Project2 in Project1, I get a long list of errors" what error did you got? Show us the details. Another thing is, a solution might have many projects that's not the issue at all. Also, we can refer one project to another unless, you refer them circularly there's shouldn't be any error or problem.
